# scanf didn't accept chars as expected

Tags: c++

Using the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

char matrix[101][101];
int row, col, case_num = 1;
int main() {
    while (scanf("%d %d", &row, &col) && row!=0 && col!=0) {
        for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<col; j++){
                scanf("%c", &matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<col; j++){
                printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I input these chars:

```
4 4
*...
....
.*..
....
0 0
```

I expected the following output:

```
*........*......
```

It's original input except white space.
But the actual output is:

```
*...
....
.*..
```

What's the problem?

Comment: There is no `<cstdio>` header in C; you're asking a C++ question. Don't dual tag.

Comment: I think this is a `c` issue rather than `c++`, more specificly, it's a `c99` style. I just edit this problem replacing `<cstdio>` with `<stdio.h>`, which should be well enough.

Comment: @armnotstrong please read [Re-tagging C++ questions as C](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281197/re-tagging-c-questions-as-c).  The tagging should go with *what compiler the original poster is actually using* , not what you think he should be using.

Comment: @MattMcNabb no, I think this is a c issue rather than a c++ issue, because no c++ feature should be needed in this issue.

Comment: @armnotstrong read the linked thread, many people have contributed. it's not just your personal opinion that counts

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have read through your referred question and I won't change my mind, as to the original poster want to compile the the answer, because a `c++` compiler **should** compile a `c` code, it's the standard. Developer searching this question should be aware that He/She comes to a C problem rather than a C++ problem. In fact, In the OP, the original poster never use a single feature of C++, if this is what the original post looks like, will you complain?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have searched the internet and come to the fact that, a C++ compiler may not compile a C code, [according to this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B), and I am tired of this argument, let's leave the OP to decide which tag should be used, will that be fair enough?

Comment: @armnotstrong yes, OP should decide, as the conclusion from the meta discussion thread I linked showed. OP is using a C++ compiler (as we can see from his line `#include <cstdio>` which is not valid in C).

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` with `%c` does **not** consume leading whitespace. So when you type in:

```
*...
```

and press Enter, that's actually five characters. This means that `matrixa[1][0]` ends up holding the `\n` character. Then when you go to output your matrix this shows up as a newline appearing in the output.

To fix all this, change the format string to `" %c"` which means to discard leading whitespace. (This also will fix the problem of eating the trailing newline from the input of the `%d %d`).